# Isolated Azure Function Dockerfile

Tags: .net, azure, docker, azure-functions, .net-5

I'm trying to dockerize isolated process .net5.0 Azure Function. But I'm getting errors. All my projects target `net5.0`. My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated:3.0-dotnet-isolated5.0-core-tools AS build

WORKDIR /app
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish My.Functions -c Release -o out -r linux-x64

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated:3.0

ENV AzureWebJobsScriptRoot=/home/site/wwwroot
ENV AzureFunctionsJobHost__Logging__Console__IsEnabled=true
ENV FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME=dotnet-isolated

COPY --from=build /app/out /home/site/wwwroot
```

The error that I'm getting says:

> It was not possible to find any compatible framework version
> [/tmp/sek2ugeb.quv/WorkerExtensions.csproj]
> /root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.net.sdk.functions/3.0.11/build/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Build.targets(32,5):
> error : The framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '3.1.0' was not
> found. [/tmp/sek2ugeb.quv/WorkerExtensions.csproj]

Why does it even try to use .net3.1?

What can I do to fix it?

Comment: When you look closely, you can see `dotnet-isolated:3.0` so it is only logical it tries dotnet 3. As it seems, you found an image for the build process, but the listed images on the [github page](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-docker) are more limited.

Comment: @b2f it fails on build... we don't get to the startup unfortunately

Comment: In your first line still stands `dotnet-isolated:3.0-isolated5.0-core-tools`, when we look on [Dockerhub](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-azure-functions-dotnet-isolated), and click on the specified link for the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-docker/blob/dev/host/3.0/buster/amd64/dotnet/dotnet-isolated/dotnet-isolated.Dockerfile). You can see where .net core 3.1 sdk originates from.
Maybe you can build before with a net5.0 sdk and then use it. A dotnet/runtime:5.0 base image is used in both of your images.

Comment: Maybe you can try to install the dependencies with the command in the Dockerfile.

Answer (score 1):

I had to put this run in my dockerfile. It installs the 3.1 sdk.

```
RUN dotnet_sdk_version=3.1.409 && curl -SL --output dotnet.tar.gz https://dotnetcli.azureedge.net/dotnet/Sdk/$dotnet_sdk_version/dotnet-sdk-$dotnet_sdk_version-linux-x64.tar.gz && mkdir -p /usr/share/dotnet && tar -ozxf dotnet.tar.gz -C /usr/share/dotnet && rm dotnet.tar.gz
```

Here is our full dotnet isolated Dockerfile:

````
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS installer-env

RUN dotnet_sdk_version=3.1.409 && curl -SL --output dotnet.tar.gz https://dotnetcli.azureedge.net/dotnet/Sdk/$dotnet_sdk_version/dotnet-sdk-$dotnet_sdk_version-linux-x64.tar.gz && mkdir -p /usr/share/dotnet && tar -ozxf dotnet.tar.gz -C /usr/share/dotnet && rm dotnet.tar.gz

COPY . /src/dotnet-function-app/

RUN mkdir -p /home/site/wwwroot

WORKDIR /src/dotnet-function-app/*FunctionName*

RUN dotnet publish --output /home/site/wwwroot

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated:3.0-dotnet-isolated5.0

ENV AzureWebJobsScriptRoot=/home/site/wwwroot \
  AzureFunctionsJobHost__Logging__Console__IsEnabled=true

COPY --from=installer-env ["/home/site/wwwroot", "/home/site/wwwroot"]```
````

Comment: Yep.. It's all quite unpleasant to say the least. I've decided to move my code to a worker service instead and forget functions altogether. I'm now happier than ever.